# Can't connect to quorum network

Tags: truffle, quorum

I am following the 7nodes example on truffle's website to setup and connect to a quorum network

http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains

I was able to get the network running on a virtualbox intance and the network is running. But when I try to truffle migrate and connect to the nodes it says.

Error: No network specified. Cannot determine current network.ild

This is my truffle config file, same as in the tutorial

```
module.exports = {
networks: {
development: {
   host: "127.0.0.1",
   port: 22000, // was 8545
   network_id: "*", // Match any network id
   gasPrice: 0,
   gas: 4500000
  }
 }
};
```

Also I am currently running a windows 10 setup. So how do i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check on which ip, your node is running. Try to ping that ip from cmd. 
ping

Then you will sure that you are connecting to the correct network